# Using the same string throughout different functions

Tags: c++, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am working on how to convert a infix to postfix expression and then calculate that converted postfix expression. I have the following thought process on how to do this.

1. **Receive** a infix expression (Through the main file)
2. **Instantiate the variables** in this expression through a function called InstantiateVariable(char, int)

   a + (2 + 2)

   where a = 2;
   THUS the values must be added accordingly before it can be parsed and converted into the postfix
3. After the infix expression is received and the variables are instantiated, I want to "convert" this infix into a postfix expression in my **shuntingYard** function. Which I have managed to do and its working.
4. Lastly, I want to **calculate/evaluate** this postfix expression that was created in my shuntingYard function.

**So basically I want to use the same string after it changes. Thus leading to my question: how can I "capture" or simply get to use the postfix string I've created in my shuntingYard function so that I can calculate/evaluate that specific string.**

Something like this:

```
void instantiateVariable(char, int)
{
    //receive the string through the main.cpp in the expression constructor
    //assign the values to the variables;
    a * (2 + 2); //set a = 3
    //Update, if you may, the "new" infix string
}

string shuntingYard(string)
{
    //Receiving this updated infix string
    //Convert it
    return the postfix string; //The converted string
}

int evaluate(string)
{
    //calculate the postfix string in the above shuntingYard function
    returns the postfix string's value;
}
```

**Here is my class I am using:**

```
class Expression
{
private:
    //string expression;
public:
    /*The constructor receives a string
    expression in infix notation*/
    Expression(string);

    /*The destructor*/
    ~Expression();

    /*Sets a value for a variable in the expression.  The
    name of the variable (first parameter) and its value
    (second parameter) are passed to this function*/

    /*Apply values to the variables in the expression*/
    void instantiateVariable(char, int);

    /*Evaluates and returns the answer to the expression*/
    int evaluate(string);

    // Function to convert Infix expression to postfix
    string shuntingYard(string);

    /*Function to verify whether an operator has higher precedence over other*/
    int higherPrecedence(char, char);

    /*Function to verify whether a character is operator symbol or not*/
    bool IsOperator(char);

    /*Function to verify whether a character is alphanumeric character (letter or numeric digit) or not*/
    bool IsOperand(char);
};
```

Comment: Is the topic relevant to the question description? Can't relate topic with description

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. If "same string" just means "avoid unnecessary copies" (for example when returning string values from functions) you should be fine with modern C++ because of move semantics. If you mean something more sophisticated (keep multiple references to the same string so that modifying one modifies'em all) I agree with @Nabin that I don't understand your code problem.

Comment: My guess is you want to use `void shuntingYard(string &s);`. That way you can write into the string `s` that has been passed and the change will be seen by the caller of `shuntingYard`.